# Connecting an open client socket to rails endpoint

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, sockets, publish-subscribe

Currently working on a project which is Vue on top of rails 4. I am consuming webhooks from the square API, and I want to be able to get that data into vue so that my data can be updated in real time as square data changes. I've asked this question before, but I'm at a slightly different point in the problem; this is getting down to the nuts and bolts.

Currently, on the server side, I have webhooks setup to fire off to a rails controller, and that works well, i can see that data coming in.

On the client side, I have a socket open and listening to that same rails controller endpoint.

What I'm having trouble with is that even though I can see the webhook hit the controller, and the socket is active, I cant seem to get the socket to pick up on the controller endpoint emitting data. Doesnt seem like the controller endpoint is passing the data along as I expect, and I suspect there is both a gap in my knowledge of rails about how to emit data properly, and how to properly consume it with a socket.

What am I missing to be able to connect the dots here?

Caveats:

1. I realize this might be possible with ActionCable, and as a last resort I may go with that, but my client is very against upgrading from rails 4 (heavy lift). If this happens to be the only way to do it, so be it, but I want to explore all other options first.
2. Im no rails expert, and have very little experience with sockets. So this whole approach might, and probably IS foolish. I also may be misunderstanding some parts of how some of these technologies work.
3. I am unfortunately, bound to using rails and vue.
4. I am working on localhost, and using ngrok to create a proper URL for the webhooks to hit. I doubt its a problem, but maybe?
5. I have explored using a node server behind the scenes and sending webhooks directly to that and listening to that server with the socket. Couldnt get that to work either, but tips on how to achieve that if its a good idea are also welcome.

For reference:

**Rails Controller:**

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
    skip_forgery_protection
    
    def order_update
        p request
        p params

        if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json'
            data = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
        else
            # application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            data = params.as_json
        end

        render json: data
    end
end
```

**Client Code (Vue && Socket):**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';

import SquareOrders from '../views/SquareOrders.vue';

import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", { 
    transports: ["polling", "flashsocket"],
    withCredentials: true,
    path: '/webhooks/order_update'
});

export default function loadOrdersApp(el, pinia) {
    const app = createApp(SquareOrders);

    app.use(pinia)
       .use(new VueSocketIO({
            debug: true,
            connection: socket
        }))
        .mount(el);
}
```

**Suggestions on better approaches are appreciated, as are corrections to my basic knowledge if I am misunderstanding something.**

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of trial and error, i managed to answer this with a different approach.

as far as I can tell, actually listening to the rails endpoint without something like ActionCable seems impossible, so I booted up and express server  to run in the background and ingest incoming webhooks.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors');

// Create a new instance of express
const app = express()

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware for JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// ALLOW OUR CLIENT SIDE TO ACCESS BACKEND SERVER via CORS
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));

// Tell our app to listen on port 3000
const server = app.listen(8080, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }

    console.log('Server started on port 8080')
})

const io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set('io', io)

// Route that receives a POST request to /webhook
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res, next) {
    const io = req.app.get('io');

    console.log(req.body)

    io.sockets.emit('orderUpdate', req.body)
    
    //res.send(req.body)
    res.sendStatus( 200 );

    next();
})

io.on('connection', function(socket){   
    console.log('A connection is made'); 
 });
```

With that in place, I pointed my webhook to localhost through ngrok, and then added logic in Vue through `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io-extended`

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

import SquareOrders from '../views/SquareOrders.vue';
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended';

import socketStore from '../stores/sockets.js';

const socket = io("http://localhost:8080", {
    transports: [ "websocket", "polling"],
});

export default function loadOrdersApp(el, pinia) {
    const app = createApp(SquareOrders);

    app.use(pinia)
       //.use(socketStore)
       .use(VueSocketIOExt, socket)
       .mount(el);
}
```

To then listen for incoming socket emits on the socket.io channel.
With those both in place, i was able to ingest those socket emissions in my frontend app

```
export default {
    name: "SquareOrders",
    components: {
        Filters,
        GlobalLoader,
        OrdersList,
        FilterGroup,
        Filter,
        OrderActions
    },
    // LISTENING FOR THE SOCKETS IN VUE COMPONENT
    sockets: {
        connect() {
            console.log('socket connected in vue')
        },
        orderUpdate(val) {
            console.log(val)
            debugger;
            
            console.log('this method was fired by the socket server. eg: io.emit("customEmit", data)')
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const os = orderStore();
        os.getOrders();
        os.getSourcesList();
        os.getSandboxOrders();

        console.log(this.$socket)

        this.$socket.client.io.on('orderUpdate', (payload) => {
            console.log(payload)
        })

        setInterval(function () {
            os.getOrders();
        }, 60000);
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(orderStore, {
            orders: store => store.orders,
            initalLoad: store => store.flags.loaded,
            filterDefs: store => store.filters.definitions,
            sandbox: store => store.sandbox
        })
    },
};
```